# Custom Function To Retrieve Table Row Value On Click

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax

I am implementing a page which dynamically builds a table with the response data from the server. I sent out the request via Ajax. Upon successful request, the code excerpt below works well to return the value I need. But upon subsequent table searches, or sorting, the clicks don't return any value whatsoever.

```
 if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
     //INITIAL DYNAMIC TABLE CREATION FROM JSON RESPONSE

     $('table tbody tr').click(function(){//PERFORM THIS WHEN A ROW IS CLICKED
          var value=$(this).find('td:first').html();
          alert(value);
     }); 
 }
```

So I thought up an alternative,  to set up an onclick attribute for each  row

```
var numberOfTDElements = document.getElementsByTagName("TD").length;
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfTDElements; i++){
    document.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].setAttribute("onclick", "clickedRow()");
}
```

Now, I have just one issue, how will I obtain row data in a custom function clickedRow() ?

That is to say, how do I replicate var *value=$(this).find('td:first').html();* in a custom function?

Is there a way to pass a DOM element or a JQuery object as a clickedRow() parameter?

Comment: What do you mean by retrieving table row value on click?

Comment: I want to get the value in the first td cell. Even if I get the value of all td cells, it is still fine as long as I can parse out what I need.

Comment: Can you share response/html of the table?

Comment: The ajax response just builds the table like any regular html table. The structure is the same. Is it the structure of the table you want to see? Or how the table looks?

Comment: What do you mean by custom function? that's basically I want to know,

Comment: I am implementing the clickedRow() function, that is why I am calling it custom. Now i need help with the implementation of the clickedRow() function. I want to know how to pass $(this) to the clickedRow() function.